# Crafting a T-SQL Query

Tags: t-sql

I have an admittedly novice question about a T-SQL query (which makes sense since I am indeed a novice when it comes to T-SQL).

Consider the following table --

```
Key    | fieldName  |    Value
==============================
465    |    Bing    |     10
465    |    Ping    |     50
846    |    Bing    |     20  
846    |    Zing    |     80  
678    |    Bing    |     10
678    |    Ping    |     50
678    |    Zing    |     20
```

How would I compose a query to return the following?

- If there exists a row with the *fieldName* `Bing` and *Value* of `10`, return all of the rows with that key, otherwise don't return any rows pertaining to that key.

In the above example, the result set should be as follows --

```
Key    | fieldName  |    Value
==============================
465    |    Bing    |     10
465    |    Ping    |     50
678    |    Bing    |     10
678    |    Ping    |     50
678    |    Zing    |     20
```

While I understand that there are likely ways better ways to reorganize the data stored in this table, I do not have control over this.  I'm happy to read any comments regarding the reorganization of the data, but I can't mark anything an answer that doesn't solve the problem as it currently exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join on the table again to find the Bing/10 values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.[Key], T1.fieldName, T1.Value
FROM YourTable T1
INNER JOIN YourTable T2 ON T1.[Key] = T2.[Key]
WHERE T2.fieldName = 'Bing' and T2.Value = 10
```

And because they're all the rage right now, here's a [SQL Fiddle demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f9ee/1).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me arrive at my solution.  I started worrying that I had abstracted away from the actual query I needed, but I did eventually get there.  Love the SQL Fiddle demo.

Answer (score 1):

Another options would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.[Key], T1.fieldName, T1.Value
FROM YourTable T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM YourTable T2
              WHERE T2.[Key] = T1.[Key]
                  AND T2.fieldName = 'Bing'
                  AND T2.Value = 10)
```